# Getting input from a file in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am currently developing an application, which gets the input from a text file and proceeds accordingly. The concept is the input file will have details in this fomat

```
A AND B
        B OR C
```

Each and every line will be seperated by a blank space and the input must be taken from the text file and processed by logic. I use a TCPP compiler and i am facing problems reading the input. Please help me with the issue...

Comment: it would help if you would post what kind of code are you currently using, or is this a HW problem?

Comment: so what is the problem that you are facing with reading the input?

Comment: No.. its not a HW problem.. The error i get is "Error reading from file" and also I am not sure how to get the line by line input from the file

Comment: Make sure the file you are reading exists and make sure you have read permission to that file from OS.

Comment: Show us the code where the problem occurs and the sample input files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading input a line at a time is normally done with `std::getline`, something like this:

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream infile("filename");

while (std::getline(line, infile))
    // show what we read
    std::cout << line << "\n";
```

If you're having trouble with things like this, you might consider looking for a (better) book on C++ than whatever you're now (hopefully) using.

Answer (score 1):

Following can be used straightaway:

```
BOOL ReadFile(CString filename)
{
    BOOL bRead = TRUE;

    std::ifstream m_strmFile;
    m_strmFile.open(filename, std::ios::in);

    char pszLine[256];
    memset(pszLine, 256, 0);

    if (m_strmFile)
    {
        // Read whatever number of lines in your file   
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5/*number of lines*/; i++)
        m_strmFile.getline(pszLine, 256);
        // Do whatever you want to do with your read lines here...
    }
    else bRead = FALSE;

    return bRead;
}
```

Comment: Are the following symbols in TCPP (Turbo C Plus Plus): `BOOL`, `CString`?  I believe those are Microsoft terms.

Comment: @ Thomas
You are correct. These terms are from MS VS. Anything wrong?
@ TCPP: please use bool and const char* instead of BOOL and CString or typedef bool BOOL

Answer (score 0):

are you using headr files like:

## include

or #include and you can make use of the fileobject.getline(), (do check its proper syntax.) function in C++ or for char by char use fileobject.get(ch) kind of function